# Angularjs testing a function that includes a $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

trying to test this function below in jasmine, it basically retires a given function n times.

```
this.retry = function (fn, n){
        return $q.when().then(function r(){
            return fn().catch(function(err){
                return (n-- <= 0) ? $q.reject(err) : r();
            });
        });
    }
```

this is my test code,

```
describe('persistenceService:retry Method', function () {
    var $q;
    var simulate;
    var qFn;
    var $rootScope;
    var $timeout;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _persistenceService_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) {
        persistenceService = _persistenceService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        simulate = function simulate(){
            return $timeout(function(){
                if(i < 4){
                    i++;
                    return $q.reject("Err");
                }
                console.log("Done");
            }, 500);
        };
        qFn = spyOn($q, 'when').andCallThrough();
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    it('should call $q.when()', function () {
        persistenceService.retry(simulate, 5);
        expect(qFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should call $q.when()', function () {
        expect(persistenceService.retry(simulate, 5)).toBe(' ');
    });
});
```

First test passes so $q is called.  However the second one gives me an output like this below,

```
 Expected { $$state : { status : 0 } } to be ' '.
```

Comment: I'm confused by what your code actually does. What is simulate supposed to do? I will try to answer your question anyway

Comment: simulate is basically there to simulate a function injection.  It's a function that returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to test the behavior rather than the interface. Here is a simplified version of your service + tests I hope helps:

Functionality: I have some function, retry, that takes a function that returns a promise, that when rejected decrements a value also passed in, and does something with the error data from the reject???

1. Simulate the promise returned by some 'fn'
2. Pass it into retry and check that retry calls it
3. Set up a promise chain, verifying that the promise is returned from retry
4. Use the promise chain (then) to check the behavior in the reject works
5. Manually reject the promise, and don't forget to $digest the scope it's in
6. Check the data processed by the reject is correct

So in code

```
this.retry = function (fn, n){
    return fn().catch(function(errorData){
        n = n - 1;
        console.log(errorData);
        return n;
    });
}

describe('persistenceService:retry Method', function () {
    var $q;
    var simulateDeferred;
    var simulate;
    var $rootScope;
    var $timeout;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _persistenceService_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) {
        persistenceService = _persistenceService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        simulateDeferred = $q.defer();
        simulate = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(simulateDeferred);
    }));

    it('should return a promise that calls the given function', function () {
        var count = 5;
        persistenceService.retry(simulate, count);
        expect(simulate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        var decrementedCount;
        simulateDeferred.reject({'error': 'some message'}).then(function(rejectResult) {
            decrementedCount = rejectResult
        });
        $rootScope.$digest(); // must be done for promise to reject / resolve
        expect(decrementedCount).toEqual(count - 1);
    });
});
```